# Searching for a matching items in between two sets with "complex in" condition

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

Lets say I have two sets:

```
set1 = set(("a", "b", 5), ("a", "c", 3))
set2 = set(("a", "b", 3), ("a", "b", 7))
```

Each item has 3 values:

1. first index (first part of the key) e.g. "a"
2. second index (second part of the key) e.g. "b"
3. third index (timestamp last part of the key) e.g 5

I want to search for all of the elements of set 1, that have the corresponding item in set2, where the corresponding item is any item that has the same value at both the first and second index, but the value of the timestamp of the matching item from the set2 must be lower than the timestamp of the item from the set1.

From the example the matching item would be:

1. <strike>("a", "b", 5) ("a", "b", 3)</strike> timestamp of 3 < 5
2. ✓ ("a", "b", 5) ("a", "b", 7)
3. <strike>("a", "c", 3) ("a", "b", 3)</strike> "c" != "b"
4. <strike>("a", "c", 3) ("a", "b", 7)</strike> "c" != "b"

Now the problem is I need to search for the items in set2 in n.log(n) time. That is why I am trying to keep the values in the set. If I was looking for the items without the timestamp:

```
set1 = set(("a", "b"), ("a", "c"))
set2 = set(("a", "b"), ("a", "b"))
```

I could do:

```
for item from set1:
  if item in set2:
    print("Found matching item")
```

But with the timestamp, I can't figure out how to implement this without two for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from `set2` where the key is the first two parts of the tuple, and the value is a list of all the timestamps. Then you can find the matching key and test if the timestamp in set1 is lower than any of them.

```
d = {}
for item in set2:
    d.setdefault(item[0:2], []).append(item[2])

for item in set1:
    if any(item[2] > x for x in set2.get(item[0:2], [])):
        print("Found match")
```

Comment: why should that be `O(nlogn)` ?

Comment: You could improve it somewhat by sorting by timestamps, but you still have to match the other fields.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I came up with a more efficient way by converting the set to a dictionary.

Comment: The dictionary value is a list. So that becomes `{("a", "b"): [5, 7]}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `O(n)` solution with `O(n)` additional space to store the `dict2` -

```
set1 = {("a", "b", 5), ("a", "c", 3)}
set2 = {("a", "b", 3), ("a", "b", 7)}

dict2 = {}
for item in set2:
    dict2[item[:2]] = max(dict2.get(item[:2], float('-inf')), item[2])

for item in set1:
    if dict2.get(item[0:2], float('-inf')) > item[2]:
        print("Found match")
        print("Match -", item, item[0:2] + (dict2.get(item[0:2]),))
```

outputs -

```
Found match
Match - ('a', 'b', 5) ('a', 'b', 7)
```

We create a new `dict2` which stores the two keys and the max timestamp seen in the `set2`, and then we loop through items in `set1` to see if for the same key if the max timestamp is larger than the timestamp in `set1` for the same key.